# How to get value bind in hidden field in a page loaded in WKWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift4, wkwebview

I need to read a value that is dynamically loaded in the input field that is in hidden on html page. I am loading that webpage in `WKWebview`.

I have few fields that I need to fill and there will be a JavaScript which executes on filling up the last field. Once the js is executed, that value is generated and bound to the input field value that is hidden.

How can I read that value?

```
Initial : <input name="xxx" type="hidden" id="xxx">
After filling the last field : <input name="xxx" type="hidden" id="xxx" value="aaaaaaaaaaa">
```

Answer (score 0):

You may read the value with JavaScript. If `xxx` is the `id` of the HTML input element you can do:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('xxx').value") { (result, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(result)
    }
}
```

The parameter `result` contains the value of the input element if `error` is `nil`.